# Swapping rows to solve a system of equations using the Gauss-Seidel method

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations

Consider the following system of equations:

\begin{align}
-2X + 5Y + 3Z + 2W = & \  42 \notag \\
-X + 2Y - 2Z + 7W = & \ 44 \notag \\
6X + Y + Z + W = & \ 21 \notag \\
X - Y + 7Z + 4W = & \ 61 \notag 
\end{align}

It is known that to solve the system of equations using the Gauss-Seidel method, the coefficients of the diagonal must be the highest coefficients of those variables.

**My question**:

If I have a matrix (like the one generated from the above system), in which the main diagonal doesn't have the largest coefficients, can I just swap rows to make it suitable for the Gauss-Seidel method?

**My attempt**:

I have looked a lot, but almost all examples already have the main diagonal with the largest coefficients.

Any help or hints are highly appreciated.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4806565/switching-rows-in-the-gauss-seidel-method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solving the system produces

$$X= 1,Y= 3,Z= 5,W= 7$$

Yes, swapping rows is a legal operation and moreover, it is required for this method to converge, see: [Switching Rows in the Gauss Seidel method](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4806565/switching-rows-in-the-gauss-seidel-method).

We cannot put the system into diagonally dominant form (due to the second row), but we at least have the rows' dominant term in the diagonal

$$ A = \left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 6 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
 -2 & 5 & 3 & 2 \\
 1 & -1 & 7 & 4 \\
 -1 & 2 & -2 & 7 \\
\end{array}
\right), ~~~ b = \left(
\begin{array}{c}
 21 \\
 42 \\
 61 \\
 44 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

Selecting a starting point of

$$x^{(1)} = \left(
\begin{array}{c}
 1 \\
 1 \\
 1 \\
 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

This results of the iteration are

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 1 & 1 & 1 & 1. \\
 3. & 8.6 & 8.94286 & 6.81224 \\
 -0.559184 & 0.0857143 & 4.9137 & 7.58526 \\
 1.40255 & 2.9787 & 4.60502 & 6.95074 \\
 1.07759 & 3.28773 & 5.05817 & 6.9455 \\
 0.951435 & 2.96748 & 5.03344 & 7.01191 \\
 0.997863 & 2.97432 & 4.98983 & 7.00413 \\
 1.00529 & 3.00656 & 4.99782 & 6.99826 \\
 0.999559 & 3.00183 & 5.00132 & 6.99979 \\
 0.99951 & 2.9991 & 5.00006 & 7.00021 \\
 1.00011 & 2.99992 & 4.99986 & 7. \\
 1.00004 & 3.0001 & 5.00001 & 6.99998 \\
 0.999984 & 2.99999 & 5.00001 & 7. \\
 0.999998 & 2.99999 & 5. & 7. \\
 1. & 3. & 5. & 7. \\
 1. & 3. & 5. & 7. \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

Compare that to the exact result above.

Even though it is not diagonally dominant, the iterations still converged. For the reasons why, see: [*Gauss-Seidel Iterative Method*](https://www3.nd.edu/%7Ezxu2/acms40390F12/Lec-7.3.pdf) and [Necessary condition for Gauss–Seidel method to converge](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3827809/necessary-condition-for-gauss-seidel-method-to-converge)

**Update** If we use the inital starting point as $(0,0,0,0)^T$, we get

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0. \\
 3.5 & 9.8 & 9.61429 & 6.73265 \\
 -0.857823 & -0.404762 & 4.93178 & 7.68789 \\
 1.46418 & 2.95145 & 4.53367 & 6.94695 \\
 1.09466 & 3.33888 & 5.06521 & 6.93533 \\
 0.943431 & 2.96412 & 5.03991 & 7.01357 \\
 0.997067 & 2.96945 & 4.9883 & 7.00497 \\
 1.00621 & 3.00752 & 4.99735 & 6.99798 \\
 0.999525 & 3.00221 & 5.00154 & 6.99974 \\
 0.999419 & 2.99895 & 5.00008 & 7.00024 \\
 1.00012 & 2.9999 & 4.99983 & 7. \\
 1.00004 & 3.00012 & 5.00001 & 6.99998 \\
 0.999982 & 2.99999 & 5.00002 & 7. \\
 0.999998 & 2.99999 & 5. & 7. \\
 1. & 3. & 5. & 7. \\
 1. & 3. & 5. & 7. \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

It converges just fine.

Comment: Thanks! I did the iterations using a C script I made myself, but the convergence is given at the 15th Iteration, and the result is like yours but with a .009, .003, .001 and .003 difference. Although the difference is a lot greater in the first iterations. Am I doing something wrong? Additionally, my professor provided a paper in which the first values of X, Y, Z and W are 0. Any idea why is that?

Comment: I am using a different tool and it uses very large precision - so likely not a problem. I also can set the precision that I want and I asked for 6 or 8 decimal places.

Comment: Yes, of course. I can't upvote since my reputation is low.

Comment: Before this question gets closed, isn't there any issue with starting calculations using X, Y, Z and W with 0?

Comment: Zero works just fine - see the update.